# PHP executing bash script gives error "Syntax error: newline unexpected"

Tags: php, bash, phantomjs

I use a PHP page to execute a command and in the errorlog of apache I see the following line, every time the command is executed by the php page. When I execute the command in terminal everything is working fine.

```
sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected
```

Here is the php:

```
exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs some-params);
```

And here is the script **/usr/bin/phantomjs**:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/phantomjs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
exec "/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs" "$@"
```

I am unable to find where the problem is. I also tried with `shell_exec`, but it gives the same error.
Can somebody see where it is or give me some guidance?

Comment: Can you add the content of `/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs`?

Comment: No, It's a "shared library (application/x-sharedlib)". I cannot see the content

Comment: But you execute it?

Comment: I execute /usr/bin/phantomjs, it uses the library

Comment: inside `/usr/bin/phantomjs` you have: `exec "/usr/lib/phantomjs/phantomjs" "$@"`.

Comment: Make sure your script is using LF and not CR-LF

Comment: @noam, so that's what you meant :) I didn't write the script it came with phantomjs and bash is not strong with me, I didn't even saw that

Comment: @Will, sorry but I have no idea what you mean. Can you please explain.

Comment: Windows and Unix systems do not encode new lines the same way. Windows uses CR-LF character, which makes scripts not runable.
You can also try to add a newline after the shebang (#!/bin/sh). Not sure you must have it but it can't harm

Comment: @Will, thank you for explaining. I found that the issue was coming from a parameter I wasn't passing properly, but I found that out after I upgraded Ubuntu and rebuilding phantomjs. Now there is another problem for me to solve. Thank you Will and noam for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other people with the same issue:
The html/string parameter must be enclosed with 'single quotes'.